# Access SQL - Count consecutive weeks with a fail

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table in Access that has a record of test results for each person for each day. Some people may have taken more than one test on the same day. I have shown a simplified version of this table below:

```
|  ID | testDate  |  Person   |   Pass? | ConsecFailDays |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  01 |  01/08/18 |  John     |  Fail   |                |
|  02 |  01/08/18 |  John     |  Pass   |                |
|  03 |  03/08/18 |  John     |  Fail   |                |
|  04 |  01/08/18 |  Mark     |  Fail   |                |
|  05 |  02/08/18 |  Mark     |  Pass   |                |
```

I have tried to write an SQL UPDATE query that will update the last column with the number of consecutive days that that person has failed at least one test (not necessarily consecutive calender days, just the days that they actually did a test). The final result should look like this...

```
|  ID | testDate  |  Person   |   Pass? | ConsecFailDays |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  01 |  01/08/18 |  John     |  Fail   |       1        |
|  02 |  01/08/18 |  John     |  Pass   |       1        |
|  03 |  03/08/18 |  John     |  Fail   |       2        |
|  04 |  01/08/18 |  Mark     |  Fail   |       1        |
|  05 |  02/08/18 |  Mark     |  Pass   |       0        |
```

I was really struggling to get this to work and in the end I resorted to using VBA to create a recordset of each unique person and then loop through each day for that person to check if they had a fail on that day. My dataset is quite large and it is taking hours to run.

I expect that a query that operates on the entire set of data would be much quicker. Does anyone know if there is an SQL solution to this after all?

Comment: Why is the last value 0 but the second 1?  You are probably better off doing this in VBA.  Although possible in MS Access, the query is way harder than it would be in other databases.

Comment: the last value is 0 because as soon as they have a week with no fails then it resets to 0. Hope that makes sense

Comment: The second value is 1 because the first two records are for the same person on the same day and there is at least one fail. Unfortunately, Access is the only DB I have available atm

Comment: Your question and comments is mixing "days / date" and "weeks", that is a bit confusing.

Comment: Oh yes, Sorry, I just meant days

Comment: The first two rows of your sample could be swapped. How do you know which comes first ?

Comment: That is correct. If there is at least one fail on that day then all records for that person on that day should have the same number in the consecFailDays

Comment: Is there an `ID` column that you left off for the purposes of the example, or does the table not have a primary key?

Comment: Yes, there is an autonumber column in the table. Sorry, should've mentioned that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need several subqueries to get the last date with a passed test and no fail, then count the days between this date and testDate:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID
    ,t1.testDate
    ,t1.Person
    ,t1.[Pass?]
    ,(
        SELECT count(testDate)
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT testDate
                ,Person
                ,[Pass?]
            FROM yourTable
            ) AS t2
        WHERE t2.[Pass?] = false
            AND t2.Person = t1.Person
            AND t2.testDate >= Nz((
                            SELECT max(t3.testDate)
                            FROM (
                                SELECT t4.testDate
                                    ,t4.Person
                                FROM yourTable AS t4
                                WHERE (
                                        ((t4.[Pass?]) = True)
                                        AND (
                                            (
                                                (
                                                    SELECT count(*) AS failed
                                                    FROM yourTable AS t5
                                                    WHERE t5.testDate = t4.testDate
                                                        AND t5.Person = t4.Person
                                                        AND t5.[Pass?] = false
                                                    )
                                                ) = 0
                                            )
                                        )
                                ) AS t3
                            WHERE t1.Person = t3.Person
                                AND t3.testDate <= [t1].[testDate]
                            GROUP BY Person
                            ))
                AND t2.testDate <= t1.testDate
        ) AS ConsecFailDays
FROM yourTable AS t1;
```

Where t2 counts the distinct days (you can drop `DISTINCT` if just one fail per day is posible to speed up).

t3 are the days with passed tests and no fail.

t4 are the days with passed tests (and maybe failed tests).

t5 counts the failed tests on a day with a passed test.

As you wanted an `Update-Query` you can use:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET ConsecFailDays = DLookUp("ConsecFailDays","newQuery","ID = " & yourTable.ID)
```

but you should try the `Select-Query` with indices first. If performance is too poor you can use the update, but you have to run it every time your data changes.

**Suggestions:**

- Don't use specialchars like `?` in `Pass?` for column or table names to avoid being forced to use square brackets.
- Person should be a foreign-key to table persons as persons can have equal names (e.g John Smith).
- [Pass?] should be boolean (true/false). If you want to stay on string you have to replace `[Pass?] = false` with `[Pass?] = 'Fail'` and `[Pass?] = true` with 
  `[Pass?] = 'Pass'`
- there should be an index for `testDate`, `Person` and a combined index for `testDate, Person` to increase query performance.

Comment: When everybody else said it couldn't be done, one man wouldn't take no for an answer. ComputerVersteher you are truly a god amongst men!

Comment: I'm quite sure my solution can be improved (this was my first more complex subquery exercise), but this is the wrong place. If you need optimized sql code, post my sql at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ with proper sample data. That's where the database pro's hang around;)